# short if-clause syntax and separating input

Tags: php, html, syntax, if-statement, foreach

I think of a syntax like:

```
$suffix1 = ($a === 1) ? 'this is one.' : 'this is:'
   foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
       ' and '
       .$keyword
  };
```

what should be like in case of `$a === 1` output: **this is one.**
in case of not `$a === 1` output: **this is: one `and` two `and` three**...

```
$keywords
```

comes from a input type text and will be splitted by:

```
$sepkeywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
```

so if there is someone who could tell me how to get this i really would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function?

```
$suffix1 = ($a === 1) ? 'this is one.' : 'this is: ' . implode(' and ', $keywords);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ask me, the shortest way would be:

```
$suffix1 = 'this is'.($a === 1 ? ' one' : ': '.implode(' and ',$keywords)).'.';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the second string into a function, and call that function inside your structure.

Answer (score 0):

you can make that foreach lopp seperate and put it into a varaible and try

some xamples 
http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

```
$suffix1 = ($a === 1) ? 'this is one.' : 'this is:'.$onetwothree
```